# Geoserver with integrated Geowebcache - How to reseed only needed tiles instead of whole layers

Tags: geoserver, tiles, geowebcache

I have a GeoServer with integrated GeoWebCache. Data is stored on a PostGIS database. I'm looking to have pre-seeded layers, but since my data is going to change several times per day, I'm looking to avoid truncating and then re-seeding the layers from scratch. Data is changed through several other applications, mainly QGIS (directly operating on the PostGIS database).

So, from my research, this can be done by [specifying a GeoRSS feed](https://www.geowebcache.org/docs/current/configuration/layers/georss.html) on the GeoWebCache configuration. This looks for an `updated` field on each RSS entry, in order to know which tiles to update.

Unfortunately, the [native Geoserver RSS implementation](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/georss/georss.html) doesn't have such a field, so I'm going to have to build one from scratch. This is fine, I doubt Geoserver would know of the changes either way, since the data is modified directly on the database.

So, the proposed solution:

- Add a timestamp `updated` field on each db layer.
- Add triggers to update that field on insert/update.
- Poll the database and generate a GeoRSS feed periodically.
- Link that feed in the GeoWebCache configuration.

My questions are:

1. How to handle deleted features? Track deletions in a separate table, and link those to the GeoRSS feed with a `null` geometry?
2. Is this the only/best way I can accomplish what I'm looking for or am I missing something?

Comment: If you could find by any means the bounding boxes of the inserted/deleted/edited features you could use the normal REST reseed tasks https://www.geowebcache.org/docs/current/webinterface/seed.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I found after further research:

Regarding #1: The GeoRSS feed must have the full geometry of the deleted entries (and not `null`), because the source code [is looking for it](https://github.com/GeoWebCache/geowebcache/blob/main/geowebcache/georss/src/main/java/org/geowebcache/georss/GeoRSSTileRangeBuilder.java) in order to generate the needed tile-extents.

Regarding #2: The GeoRSS route is overkill and not really needed. Since I'll be adding triggers to the database anyway, a faster option is to use [GeoWebCache's REST api](https://www.geowebcache.org/docs/current/rest/seed.html) to reseed just the extents that changed.

So to recap:

- Add a mechanism to do API queries based on database triggers. (For example [this](https://github.com/graphile/worker), or [this](https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-http))
- Add triggers to the related db tables.
- Call the GeoWebCache `Seed` API endpoint, everytime a geometry is inserted/modified/deleted with that geometry's extents.